# How do you go through an email inbox with SeleniumLibrary in Robot Framework?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

Specifically, I want to use SeleniumLibrary to accept a confirmation email. The account I am accessing is a Gmail account. I already automated the log in without a problem, but I cannot find the correct name, nor id, in the HTML source code of the Gmail inbox to which to set the locator. I'm just trying to access an email automatically.

Comment: I had a similar task once. I was using the selenium java bindings, so I found it easier to use the Java Mail API to access Gmail via IMAP directly. I don't know if that fits your needs, but depending on which language you are using, maybe accessing via POP3/IMAP with a non-selenium API could be an option ...

Comment: Thank you, I have looked into using IMAP before. It could be an option, I will have to look into it more.

Answer (score 1):

May be easier to use the [robotframework-imaplibrary](https://github.com/lovelysystems/robotframework-imaplibrary)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

First is to get a `List<WebElement>` found by `By.cssSelector(".zA")`, and iterate through them until you find the one that contains the text you want.

I don't like that solution, partially because `.zA` is minimized CSS (and therefore, may change), and is not descriptive.

I think the best solution is to use IMAP, as Stefan has described.  It is also *much* faster than Selenium.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try. IMAP could be an option, but I'm trying to find a way with Selenium first.